# Is there a way to store a list of commands in Visual Studio for Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, command, repository, package-manager-console

We're switching from a classic Desktop application project, where everything fitted nicely within Visual Studio, to an Angular Web Project, where everything seems to be scattered over different environments all over the place.

One of the changes is nuget packages, which makes me feel like we're back in the 80's, where everything needs to be done with commands in Command Prompt, instead of just using buttons and menus. I find this slightly annoying, as now you have to remember a long list of commands where previously you could just remember a button's location.

Is there a place where you can store a list of commands that you can browse in your Package Manager Console? For instance, if I forget the command that script my model into SQL Scripts, I can just browse the list, instead of looking for the email where a colleague told me what it was?

Answer (score -2):

The Package Manager Console is a PowerShell session, so you could create a PowerShell script Module with everything in it.

And even load from your profile (for package manager specific use file: run `$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost` in the console to get the path).